# Mostrar un alert y después redireccionar en Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Me gustaría saber como puedo redireccionar a otra página, por ejemplo al home después de haber insertado un dato.

Lo que uso actualmente es esto:

```
redirect("PaquetesController");

    $this->db->insert(TABLE_PRODUCTOS,$data);
         echo "<script>alert('Estás suscrito, ¡Gracias!.');</script>";
         // redirect("PaquetesController");
```

Pero no me muestra la alerta, solo me redirecciona.

Comment: `echo "<script>alert('Estás suscrito, ¡Gracias!.'); window.location.assign('Nuevaurl') </script>";`. No se de codeigniter asi que no se cómo convertir el controller en url

Comment: Eso solo le agrega en en este caso `Nuevaurl`. por ejemplo `localhost/proyecto/usuarios/Nuevaurl`  pero lo que requiero es que redireccione a `localhost/proyecto/usuarios` es decir, a la misma página.

Comment: Supongo que para guardar los datos tienes un boton en la vista, si es asi, genera un evento onClick en el boton, y dentro pon el **alert** y la redireccion **window.location.href = "http://es.stackoverflow.com"**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo resolví agregando `"refresh"`:

```
$this->db->insert(TABLE_PRODUCTOS,$data);

echo "<script>alert('Estás suscrito, ¡Gracias!.');</script>";

 redirect('PaquetesController', 'refresh');
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu código puede reescribirse de esta forma

```
$this->db->insert(TABLE_PRODUCTOS,$data);
     echo "<script>" + 
              "alert('Estás suscrito, ¡Gracias!.');" + 
              "window.location.assign('" + site_url("/controller/method") + "')"
          "</script>";
```

Simplemente llama a [window.location.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign) para mostrar una nueva url luego que el usuario haya presionado "ok" y usas [`site_url()`](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) para generar la url correcta en tu sitio.

Recuerda que `redirect`

> Hace una "redirección de cabecera" al URI especificado

Esa es la razón por la que el método no te funciona ya que este tipo de [redireccion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection) es interpretada por el navegador y en tu caso lo que necesitas es una redirección con javascript luego que el usuario haya visto la página y presionado el botón del `alert`

Comment: Gracias  pero no me funciona, me manda la misma página en blanco con un 0.

Comment: @x4mp73r Tienes que reemplazar `site_url("/controller/method")` por tu correspondiente controller y método. El ejemplo lo puse a modo general por eso quizás no te funciona.

Comment: Así es, se que solo era un ejemplo `site_url`.  No funciona

Comment: Si la url en el navegador cambió la redirección se hizo correctamente y el error está en el controller al que estás intentando navegar. Verifica que el helper haya sido cargado con `$this->load->helper('url');` puedes crear un breakpoint escribiendo `echo "<script>debugger;alert(....</script>"` y al presionar F12 en las herramientas de Chrome para desarrolladores te pausará la ejecución antes del alert para que puedas verificar si la url se está imprimiendo correctamente en la pestaña "Elements" del debugger.

Comment: En efecto, se que existe la consola y todo eso. Pero la url no cambia, solo me muestra un 0 en la misma página. Ya lo eh solucionado, ahora mismo coloco la solución.
¡Te agradezco por tu tiempo en verdad! :D